# Calling a widget from another class to change its properties in tKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have made a function in the main constructor of my tKinter app which updates certain properties of widgets e.g. their text across multiple frames. What I'm trying to do is change widgets in multiple frames at the same time while in a controller frame.

```
def update_widgets(self, frame_list, widget_name, criteria, output):
    for i in frame_list:

        i.widget_name.config(criteria=output)

# update_widgets(self, [Main, AnalysisSection], text_label, text, "foo")
# would result in Main.text_label_config(text="foo") and 
# AnalysisSection.text_label_config(text="foo") ideally.
```

However with this code, I'm encountering two problems. Firstly, I'm getting an attribute error stating that both frames don't have the attribute **widget_name**. Secondly, when I tried to refer to the widget names with the self prefix, both frames say they don't have the attribute **self**. Is there a way to fix this?

Full program below:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Root(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.frames = {}

    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="bottom", expand=True)#fill="both", expand=True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    for X in (A, B):
        frame=X(container, self)
        self.frames[X]=frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(A)

def show_frame(self, page):
    frame = self.frames[page]
    frame.tkraise()

def update_widgets(self, frame_list, widget_name, criteria, output):
    for i in frame_list:
        frame = self.frames[i]
        widget = getattr(frame, widget_name)
        widget[criteria] = output



class A(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):

         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

         self.controller = controller

         self.text = 'hello'

         self.classLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Frame A")

         self.classLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP)

         # trying to change this widget
         self.wordLabel = tk.Label(self, text="None")
         self.wordLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP)

         self.changeTextLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Change text above across both frames").pack(side=tk.TOP)
         self.changeTextEntry = tk.Entry(self, bg='pink')
         self.changeTextEntry.pack(side=tk.TOP)

         self.changeFrameButton = tk.Button(text="Change to Frame B", command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(B))
         self.changeFrameButton.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

         self.changeTextEntryButton = tk.Button(self, text="ENTER", width=5, command=lambda: self.controller.update_widgets([A, B], 'self.wordLabel', 'text', self.changeTextEntry.get()))
         self.changeTextEntryButton.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)


         ### calling this function outside of the button; this is already
         ### called within a function in my project.
         x = self.controller.update_widgets([A, B], 'wordLabel', 'text', '*initial change*')



class B(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):

       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

       self.controller = controller

       self.text = 'hello'

       self.classLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Frame B")

       self.classLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP)

       # trying to change this widget
       self.wordLabel = tk.Label(self, text="None")
       self.wordLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP)

       self.changeTextLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Change text above across both frames").pack(side=tk.TOP)
       self.changeTextEntry = tk.Entry(self, bg='light yellow').pack(side=tk.TOP)

       self.changeFrameButton = tk.Button(text="Change to Frame A", command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(A))
       self.changeFrameButton.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

       self.changeTextEntryButton = tk.Button(self, text="ENTER", width=5, command=lambda: self.controller.update_widgets([A, B], 'self.wordLabel', 'text', self.changeTextEntry.get()))
       self.changeTextEntryButton.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = Root()
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue. The origin of your problem is cannot be identified with the code you have provided.

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. The code can't run as posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're trying to get an attribute of a *class* rather than an *instance* of a class. You need to convert `i` to the actual instance of that class. You have the additional problem that you're passing `'self.wordLabel'` rather than just `'wordLabel'`.

A simple fix is to look up the instance in `self.frames`

```
def update_widgets(self, frame_list, widget_name, criteria, output):
    for i in frame_list:
        frame = self.frames[i]
        label = getattr(frame, widget_name)
        label[criteria] = output
```

You also need to change the button command to look like this:

```
self.changeTextEntryButton = tk.Button(... command=lambda: self.controller.update_widgets([A,B], 'wordLabel', 'text', self.changeTextEntry.get()))
```

If you intend for `update_widgets` to always update all of the page classes, there's no reason to pass the list of frame classes in. Instead, you can just iterate over the known classes:

```
def update_widgets(self, widget_name, criteria, output):
    for frame in self.frames.values():
        label = getattr(frame, 'classLabel')
        label[criteria] = output
```

You would then need to modify your buttons to remove the list of frame classes:

```
self.changeTextEntryButton = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: self.controller.update_widgets('wordLabel', 'text', self.changeTextEntry.get()))
```

Comment: frame_list is a list of frames in my application; I'm attempting to refer to a specific widget within both frames (Main and AnalysisSection) and changing one of the selected widget's properties.

Comment: @Azidic: I apologize; I didn't read your original question closely enough. I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but for some reason getattr doesn't work with class attributes referring to the object (self) that are within the constructor. (AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'self.classLabel')

Comment: @Azidic: the reason it doesn't work is that, although you implied that `frame_list` was a list of frames, in your updated question I see that it is not. It is a list of frame _classes_.  There's a big difference between the two.

Comment: I have one more question: how do you call `update_widgets` within the constructor without using a button to do it? When I ran this line of code in class A (Updated in question) `x = self.controller.update_widgets([A, B], 'wordLabel', 'text', '*initial change*')` it returned this error: `KeyError: <class '__main__.A'>`. Using lambda in this function call made no difference yet fixed the key error.

Comment: @Azidic The way you call it is exactly like any other function: `self.controller.update_widgets(...)`. I can't tell from your error why it didn't work, but that's how you do it. You must have called it before all of the pages were created. Instead of just copying and pasting code, you need to try to understand what the code is doing.