# How to, in class 1, change the properties of a widget (label) in class 2 (Tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, tk-toolkit

I am trying to have a `recordBn` button in `MainMenu` Class that change the text of `dateLb` label in `RecordTime` class. But I keep getting Error message as below.

`AttributeError: 'RecordTime' object has no attribute 'dateLb'`

Using the `empcbxlist()` of `GFPTime` Class

I have tried to solve my problem from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531729/calling-a-widget-from-another-class-to-change-its-properties-in-tkinter) and several other post with same error message (`AttributeError`), But couldn't find a solution. Help me to solve my error

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os.path
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
# from PIL import Image, ImageTk
# from dbfunctions import *
import datetime

class GFPTime(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"GFP Employee Timecard System")
        tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self,"800x480+0+0")

        container =tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand= True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainMenu,RecordTime):

            frame = F(container,self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,stick='nsew')

        self.show_frame(MainMenu)
        # print(self.frames.values())
    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def empcbxlist(self, widget_name, criteria, output):
        # db = TimeCardDB()
        # cbvalue = db.listActiveEmployees()
        # db.dbclose()

        widget = getattr(RecordTime,'dateLb')
        widget[criteria] = output

###
class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        #tk.Frame.configure(self,background='red')
        font9 = "-family {Minion Pro} -size 14 -weight bold"
        self.controller = controller

        recordBn = tk.Button(self,command=lambda: [self.controller.show_frame(RecordTime), self.controller.empcbxlist('self.dateLb','text','yessss')])
        recordBn.place(relx=0.269, rely=0.646, height=50, width=180)
        recordBn.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        recordBn.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        recordBn.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        recordBn.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        recordBn.configure(font=font9)
        recordBn.configure(foreground="#000000")
        recordBn.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        recordBn.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        recordBn.configure(pady="0")
        recordBn.configure(text='''Record Time''')#!/usr/bin/python


class RecordTime(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        dateLb = tk.Label(self)
        dateLb.place(relx=0.213, rely=0.021, height=38, width=144)
        dateLb.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        dateLb.configure(activeforeground="black")
        dateLb.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        dateLb.configure(font="-family {Minion Pro} -size 14 -weight bold")
        dateLb.configure(foreground="#000000")
        dateLb.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        dateLb.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        dateLb.configure(text='''SHOW DATE''')



GFPTime().mainloop()
```

Comment: There is too much code here. Please remove as much code as possible whilst still leaving the essence of your question. Oh, and also format it so that it is readable to python programmers please.

Comment: It is because `dateLb` is local variable inside `__init__(...)` of `RecordTime` class and so it cannot be accessed outside the class.  Replace `dateLb` to `self.dateLb` in `RecordTime` class.

Comment: @acw1668: That won't fix the issue because he is not getting the attribute from the class that he saved in the list `self.frame` instead he is calling it directly from the class which doesn't have an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.

1. When you've create a dictionary `self.frames` and saving the object of each frame with their class name then use the dictionary to get their methods and attributes don't use a class name like `widget = getattr(RecordTime,'dateLb')` to access them instead of `RecordTime` use the class the you saved in the dictionary.
2. Don't give widget name `self.dateLb` in the lambda function just `dateLb` should be enough.

   Change:

   `self.controller.empcbxlist('self.dateLb','text','yessss')`

   To

   `self.controller.empcbxlist('dateLb','text','yessss')`
3. As @aw1668 said *"Replace `dateLb` to `self.dateLb` in `RecordTime` class"* So globalise `dateLb` label by changing it to `self.dateLb`.

I changed the block of code inside `empcbxlist()` to this.

```
def empcbxlist(self, widget_name, criteria, output):
    # db = TimeCardDB()
    # cbvalue = db.listActiveEmployees()
    # db.dbclose()

    # Get the frame. 
    ob = self.frames.get( RecordTime ) 
    widget = getattr(ob,widget_name)
    widget[criteria] = output

    # can use this to change the text to be on safe side.
    # for i, j  in self.frames.items():
    #     if i.__name__ == RecordTime.__name__:
    #         widget = getattr(j,widget_name)
    #         widget[criteria] = output
```

**Complete code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os.path
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
# from PIL import Image, ImageTk
# from dbfunctions import *
import datetime

class GFPTime(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"GFP Employee Timecard System")
        tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self,"800x480+0+0")

        container =tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand= True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainMenu,RecordTime):

            frame = F(container,self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,stick='nsew')

        self.show_frame(MainMenu)
        # print(self.frames.values())
    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def empcbxlist(self, widget_name, criteria, output):
        # db = TimeCardDB()
        # cbvalue = db.listActiveEmployees()
        # db.dbclose()

        ob = self.frames.get( RecordTime ) 
        widget = getattr(ob,widget_name)
        widget[criteria] = output

###
class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        #tk.Frame.configure(self,background='red')
        font9 = "-family {Minion Pro} -size 14 -weight bold"
        self.controller = controller

        recordBn = tk.Button(self,command=lambda: [self.controller.show_frame(RecordTime), self.controller.empcbxlist('dateLb','text','yessss')])
        recordBn.place(relx=0.269, rely=0.646, height=50, width=180)
        recordBn.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        recordBn.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        recordBn.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        recordBn.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        recordBn.configure(font=font9)
        recordBn.configure(foreground="#000000")
        recordBn.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        recordBn.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        recordBn.configure(pady="0")
        recordBn.configure(text='''Record Time''')#!/usr/bin/python


class RecordTime(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.dateLb = tk.Label(self)
        self.dateLb.place(relx=0.213, rely=0.021, height=38, width=144)
        self.dateLb.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.dateLb.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.dateLb.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.dateLb.configure(font="-family {Minion Pro} -size 14 -weight bold")
        self.dateLb.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.dateLb.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.dateLb.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.dateLb.configure(text='''SHOW DATE''')



GFPTime().mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Sorry for the messy code/post, long night trying to solve this, and still a noob with python and posting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit messy, and over complicated. I've reduced it to a more digestible size - the embellishments were only adding to the clutter of the code.

Please stare at it until you understand what elements are doing what, and, maybe, rebuild from there.

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime


class GFPTime(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super().wm_title("GFP Employee Timecard System")
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand= True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MainMenu, RecordTime):    
            self.frames[F] = F(self.container, self)
            self.frames[F].grid(row=0,column=0,stick='nsew')
        self.show_frame(MainMenu)

    def show_frame(self, container):
        self.frames[container].tkraise()

    def empcbxlist(self, text_value):
        self.show_frame(RecordTime)
        self.frames[RecordTime].date_lbl.configure(text=text_value)


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller
        record_btn = tk.Button(self, text='Record Time', 
                             command=lambda text_value=str(datetime.date.today()): self.controller.empcbxlist(text_value))
        record_btn.pack()


class RecordTime(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.date_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='SHOW DATE')
        self.date_lbl.pack()


GFPTime().mainloop()
```

Comment: Your suggestion will remove the flexibility of changing different attributes of the `RecordTime` class in the original OP design.

Comment: Yes it does. The code is originally copied from a post by Bryan Oakley, but has seen so many variations, that it has become ungainly. The point is getting to something simple enough that (1) it works, and (2) that the OP understands what it does, and how... then add functionality back into it.